# 3g модем написание софта

Tags: модемы, at

Здравствуйте кодеры.

Есть такая штукенция как Oktell sip gsm Gateway, которая позволяет подключить голосовой 3g модем (обычные 3g модемы) в usb, настроить sip аккаунт и звонить через него.
Однако сие чудо стоит денег.

Я вот задумался, а что если написать свой софт под модем. Из компа ведь можно сделать целую станцию, управляемую через обычный телефон. В общем фантазия безгранична.
Модем управляет AT командами, нашел учебник по АТ командам, однако модем Huawei e160g половину их не поддерживает... Я научился только принимать вызовы, а совершать их и уж тем более слышать звук через колонки и гооворить через микрофон не получается. В чем фишка?

В данный момент уже реализована шуточная программа: при подключении данного модема к любому компу программа сама запускается в скрытом режиме и при звонке на этот номер комп ребутится - можно тайком воткнуть в usb товарища по работе. =))

Answer (score 2):

Говорить и не получится. У чипсета таких модемов есть отдельные линии для голосовой связи. Звук не передается через цифровой интерфейс. Советую попробовать модем-модуль SimCom. У них их линейка, например 900-й. Или Wismo. С ними легко работать. Как с обычным модемом + голосовая связь + Смс. Вот только питание на них отдельно нужно подавать и с СОМ-портом или USB сопрягать. В этом плане ваш Хуавей предпочтительнее - законченное устройство. А каких именно команд не понимает, кстати?

Comment: спасибо ро симком почитал..фишка интересная..но телось бы сделать на том что имеется в руках..тобишь "побесплатнее"=)
есть вот учебник для прогроммарей этих модемов..только учебник прямо так скажем позорный.. так как написано чисто..если нажать сюда..должно выскочить так..если не выскочило..значит ERRoR=)) а че такое почему хрен знает
вот учебнег половина команд из него наподобии набор номера http://rghost.ru/7146751

Comment: помимо huawei звук ещё передается и на всех модемах zte

Answer (score 0):

Модем может не поддерживать голосовой звонок. Чтобы проверить режимы, обеспечиваемые модемом, выполните из терминала команду:

```
AT+FCLASS=?
```

Если в ответ вы получите сообщение ERROR или список цифр, не содержащий 8 (голосовой режим), то голосовой звонок не поддерживается.

Comment: модем полностью поддерживает голосовой вызов стандартными программами Mobile Partner.. звуонить можно и отправлять смс можно тоже и звук слышен через колонки и можно говорить через микрофон.. все проверено..с этим вопросов нет прошил все верно.. вопрос в том чтобы написать свой софт под модем или хотя бы найти команды которыми он управляется

Comment: Максимум, чем могу помочь - проснифайте трафик как на виртуальном COM-порту, так и на самом USB. Программы для этого существуют. Хотя толку от этого ^^"