# Написание софта для 3g модема

Tags: модемы, at

Есть 3g модем от Huawey, модель e160g([вот такой](http://iskitimcity.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/e160g.jpg)) разлочен, перепрошит оригинальной прошивкой от huawey. Умеет звонить командой `ATD+79001234567;` Ответить на вызов `ATA`, сбросить вызов `AT+CHUP`.

Проблема следующая. Как выводить звук на звуковую карту и принимать звук с микрофона, какими командами или чем вообще? На модеме естественно нет никаких разъемов под звук.
Однако родная программа от Huawey позволяет совершать голосовые вызовы через комп (через звуковую карту компьютера). Как сие в ней организовано?

Так же, чем можно поснифать (послушать/увидеть) команды которыми обменивается программа с модемом.

[Книжка](http://www.compel.ru/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%A2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B.pdf) по at командам, которой пользуюсь, в ней подобного не описано (перерыл все, но может быть упустил чего?).

Задавал [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14585/at-3g-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0) давненько, но ответа так и не получил... вернулся к старым мыслям, есть желание воплотить в жизнь!

Answer (score 1):

Большинство модемов в Windows садятся на драйвер [Unimodem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/hardware/ff543158(v=vs.85).aspx). Этот драйвер поддерживает звук (Voice Modem) через Wave Device. Все управление модемом осуществляется в конечном счете через COM порт напрямую или через TAPI. Можно посмотреть в диспетчере устройств, на каком порту сидит модем. Увидеть какие команды шлет программа модему можно с помощью утилиты [portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx). Нужно подключиться к порту модема и слушать его, тогда программа выведет в лог AT-команды, которыми она обменивается с модемом.